# Is there a way that can record the steps history when debug Java?

Tags: java, debugging

I'm debugging a complex java application and condition 1 and condition 2 both execute method A. but they got different result, so I want to find the key point in the method A. but the flow in method A is quite complex that it's hard to compare step by step. so I consider find a way to record the steps so that I can compare and find the difference quickly.

Answer (score 0):

If you use some IDE, then set some breakpoint and run it with debug mode, and you will watch the value of variables.

Maybe you could draw control-flow on paper to help thinking.

sysout is my usual debug way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Log4j to record your debug information in file or database.